# Creating select list in half-hour increments

Tags: php, select, time

I have two variables: `$start_time` and `$end_time`. These values are times in 24 hour `XX:XX` format, and always end with either `:00` or `:30`. They are supposed to define a range that determines times that appear in a drop-down select list in a HTML form, but the form displays the format in `X:XX am/pm` notation.

For example, if I have these values:

```
$start_time = "11:00";
$end_time   = "13:30";
```

What PHP code do I use to generate a select list which looks like this?

```
<option value="11:00">11:00 am</option>
<option value="11:30">11:30 am</option>
<option value="12:00">12:00 pm</option>
<option value="12:30">12:30 pm</option>
<option value="13:00">1:00 pm</option>
<option value="13:30">1:30 pm</option>
```

I know how to accomplish this by building an array of all possible values manually and then working backwards, but there must be a much more elegant way that uses PHP's built-in time functions.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think your array idea is pretty good. Got for it!

Comment: I wouldn't go overkill with this. You can acommpish this with a fairly simple algorithm. I'll see if i can write one in an answer below

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Fairly straightforward with a little [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/strtotime) and [date()](http://www.php.net/date) magic:

Consider:

```
<?php
$start = "11:00";
$end = "13:30";

$tStart = strtotime($start);
$tEnd = strtotime($end);
$tNow = $tStart;

while($tNow <= $tEnd){
  echo date("H:i",$tNow)."\n";
  $tNow = strtotime('+30 minutes',$tNow);
}
```

Getting stuff properly formatted and output in  tags is left as an exercise, see the docs for date().

Comment: Beautiful. Exactly the kind of thing I was shooting for. Gracias.

Comment: consider that a simpler script taht doenst' need to call date and strtotime would be much much faster (i gave +1 here anyway)

Comment: You could write that `while` as a `for`. If you feel like golfing: http://codepad.org/LcKmWheb

Comment: @Christopher - nice succinct solution!  @yes123 - and writing it in C as a PHP extension would be even faster still, and just as premature.

Comment: What happens if that code starts to run at 23:59:59 and while running a new day begins?

Comment: @hakre - I suppose if the day rolled over between the two initial assignments, that could cause problems.  Using an explicit (though irrelevant) date might be advisable.

Comment: Exactly why I love stackoverflow...pefect!

Answer (score 7):

This seems to produce you what you want too..

```
$start=strtotime('10:00');
$end=strtotime('21:30');
for ($halfhour=$start;$halfhour<=$end;$halfhour=$halfhour+30*60) {
    printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>',date('H:i',$halfhour),date('g:i a',$halfhour));
}
```

Comment: You should try to prevent calculation in your loops.

Comment: Well, yes @PeeHaa, you're not wrong. However - in a loop like this that does a simple calculation a handful of times the clarity might well outweigh the performance hit. But as a principle, the 30*60 should be replaced with 1800.

Comment: Best answer for adding am:pm times.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know that you can use php's date and time functions as those are more for handling specific times, but here is a more elegant solution in general:

```
$options = array();
foreach (range(0,24) as $fullhour) {
   $parthour = $fullhour > 12 ? $fullhour - 12 : $fullhour;
   $parthour .= $fullhour > 11 ? " pm" : " am";
   $options["$fullhour:00"] = $parthour;
   $options["$fullhour:30"] = $parthour;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i think this is the correct way, based on your code.

    $options = array();
    foreach (range(0,23) as $fullhour) 
    {
        $parthour = $fullhour > 12 ? $fullhour - 12 : $fullhour;
        $sufix = $fullhour > 11 ? " pm" : " am";
        $options["$fullhour:00"] = $parthour.":00".$sufix;
       $options["$fullhour:30"] = $parthour.":30".$sufix;}

Answer (score 3):

Try this to create array of time with 30 min interval. I have tested it.

```
    $options = array(); $min30=array('00','30');
    foreach (range(0,23) as $fullhour) {
       $parthour = $fullhour > 12 ? $fullhour - 12 : $fullhour;
        foreach($min30 as $int){
            if($fullhour > 11){
                $options[$fullhour.".".$int]=$parthour.":".$int." PM";
            }else{
                if($fullhour == 0){$parthour='12';}
                $options[$fullhour.".".$int]=$parthour.":".$int." AM" ;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($options);
```

Answer (score 2):

A different approach could be to completely solve your issue using PHP by using the DateTime object:

```
// Make a DateTime object with the current date and time
$today = new DateTime();

// Make an empty array to contain the hours
$aHours = array();

// Make another DateTime object with the current date and time
$oStart = new DateTime('now');

// Set current time to midnight
$oStart->setTime(0, 0);

// Clone DateTime object (This is like 'copying' it)
$oEnd = clone $oStart;

// Add 1 day (24 hours)
$oEnd->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));

// Add each hour to an array
while ($oStart->getTimestamp() < $oEnd->getTimestamp()) {
    $aHours[] = $oStart->format('H');
    $oStart->add(new DateInterval("PT1H"));
}

// Create an array with halfs
$halfs = array(
    '0',
    '30',
);

// Get the current quarter
$currentHalf = $today->format('i') - ($today->format('i') % 30);
```

Then to print:

```
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="-1">Choose a time</option>
    <?php foreach ($aHours as $hour): ?>
        <?php foreach ($halfs as $half): ?>
            <option value="<?= sprintf("%02d:%02d", $hour, $half); ?>" <?= ($hour == $today->format('H') && $half == $currentHalf) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                <?= sprintf("%02d:%02d", $hour, $half); ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

In the above example you will generate a dropdown with all hours of a day. The current hour and half hour will be automatically selected.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Explosion Pills code, i think this is the correct way.

```
$options = array();
foreach (range(0,23) as $fullhour) 
{
    $parthour = $fullhour > 12 ? $fullhour - 12 : $fullhour;
    $sufix = $fullhour > 11 ? " pm" : " am";

    $options["$fullhour:00"] = $parthour.":00".$sufix;
    $options["$fullhour:30"] = $parthour.":30".$sufix;
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the typo.  The original didn't use the suffix variable.  You may also want to include an `options["0:00"]="12:00$am";options["0:30"]="12:30am";` at the start (and adjust the range to start at 1) for a easier midnight hour reading.

Answer (score 1):

This is a full working version and I'm using it (modified from above).  The change I made was have the value of the option tag formatted for entry into a sql db. I also changed 00:00 to midnight and 12:00 to noon.

(Edited again to show selection option)

```
<select name="starttime">
<?php 
foreach (range(0,23) as $fullhour) {
$fullhour2digit = strlen($fullhour)==1 ? '0' . $fullhour : $fullhour;
$parthour = $fullhour > 12 ? $fullhour - 12 : $fullhour;
$parthour .= $fullhour > 11 ? ":00 pm" : ":00 am";
$parthour = $parthour=='0:00 am' ? 'midnight' : $parthour;
$parthour = $parthour=='12:00 pm' ? 'noon' : $parthour;

$parthalf = $fullhour > 12 ? $fullhour - 12 : $fullhour;
$parthalf .= $fullhour > 11 ? ":30 pm" : ":30 am";


//SHOWS THE TEST FOR 'SELECTED' IN THE OPTION TAG
     echo '<option ';
     if (date("H:i:s", strtotime($startdate)) === $fullhour2digit . ':00:00')
        {echo ' SELECTED ';}
     echo 'value="' . $fullhour2digit . ':00:00">' .  $parthour . '</option>';
     echo '<option ';
     if (date("H:i:s", strtotime($startdate)) === $fullhour2digit  . ':30:00')
        {echo ' SELECTED ';}
     echo 'value="' . $fullhour2digit . ':30:00">' .  $parthalf . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

This outputs (truncated)...

```
<select name="starttime">
<option value="00:00:00">midnight</option><option value="00:30:00">0:30 am</option>
 ....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select>
  <?php
     $h = 0;
     $m = 0;
     while ($h != 24.5) {
       if(strpos($h,".") !== false){
           $v = ($h-0.5).'30';
       }else{
           $v = $h.'00';
       }
       if ($h < 10) {
           $v = '0'.$v;
       }
       echo '<option>'.$v.'</option>';

       $h = $h + 0.5;
     }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Add some description to answer.@Wewo Brian

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for 12 hours with AM/PM:

```
<?php
$steps   = 15; // only edit the minutes value
$current = 0;
$loops   = 24*(60/$steps);

for ($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++) {
    $hour = $i/(60/$steps);
    $time = sprintf('%02d:%02d %s', $hour, $current%60, intval($hour/12) == 0 ? ' AM' : ' PM');
    echo '<option>'.$time.'</option>';
    $current += $steps;
}
?>
```

And for 24 hours:

```
<?php
$steps   = 15; // only edit the minutes value
$current = 0;
$loops   = 24*(60/$steps);

for ($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++) {
    $time = sprintf('%02d:%02d', $i/(60/$steps), $current%60);
    echo '<option>'.$time.'</option>';
    $current += $steps;
}
?>
```